# Unable to access current_user attributes in Cells

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cells

I have a RoR app using Devise with a User table for user authentication. I'm using the cells in the following manner:

```
class EnrollmentCell < Cell::Rails

  def show(current_user)
    logger.debug "This is the current user: #{current_user}"
    user = current_user

    logger.debug "This is the ID of the user: #{user.id}"
    logger.debug "This is the ID of the user: #{user.email}"
end
```

The log is showing that the current_user hash is being received:

```
Started GET "/" for ::1 at 2015-04-14 23:03:16 -0700
Processing by VisitorsController#index as HTML
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
  Enrollment Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "enrollments".* FROM "enrollments" WHERE "enrollments"."user_id" = ?  [["user_id", 2]]
This is the current user: {:user=>#<User id: 2, email: "testuser@mac.com", encrypted_password: "$2a$10$QfdzPmD/QqvFUu31Qn43x.u9h6qKiIzdWXtAcAoAK1O...", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 4, current_sign_in_at: "2015-04-15 01:25:28", last_sign_in_at: "2015-04-13 16:32:09", current_sign_in_ip: "::1", last_sign_in_ip: "::1", created_at: "2015-04-11 14:29:28", updated_at: "2015-04-15 01:25:28", name: "Steve Smith", confirmation_token: nil, confirmed_at: "2015-04-11 14:29:46", confirmation_sent_at: "2015-04-11 14:29:29", unconfirmed_email: nil, role: 0>}
  Rendered visitors/index.html.erb within layouts/application (39.1ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 43ms (ActiveRecord: 1.1ms)

NoMethodError - undefined method `id' for #<Hash:0x007fa0c420f960>:
  app/cells/enrollment_cell.rb:7:in `show'
```

I would have expected to be able to access the "id" and "email" of "user". I can't seem to figure out why I am unable to access this information, but I'm sure there is something simple that I'm overlooking here.

Comment: Seems like the user object you want is a hash inside `current_user` with `:user` key. Try accessing it by `user[:user].id` or `user.user.id`.

Comment: I suggest you please write `logger.debug "===#{user.inspect}"` and check whether the `user` variable is an object or hash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write this class as below shown:

```
class EnrollmentCell < Cell::Rails

  def show(current_user)
    logger.debug "This is the current user: #{current_user}"
    user = current_user

    logger.debug "This is the ID of the user: #{user[:user].id}"
    logger.debug "This is the ID of the user: #{user[:user].email}"
  end
end
```

Comment: OK. I am able to access these attributes in the manner you describe. As a fairly junior RoR developer I guess I'm confused as to why I must access the attributes in this fashion as opposed to simply accessing them with user.id. Can you please provide this explanation?

Comment: @acoustic_north Reason your user is get passed as hash as opposed to object. It is key & value pair. Your key is :user and value is your user object. So you must access as it you are accessing your hash object.